# Can I create a git repository for several directories which don't necessarily share an ancestor directory except root `/`?

Tags: git

To turn any directory into a Git repository, we run:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
```

Does that mean a Git repository is created only for a single directory?

Can I create a Git repository for several directories which don't necessarily share an ancestor directory except root `/`? For example, can we create a repository for `~/dir1/dir2/dir3` and `~/dir4/dir5`? Can we create a repository for `~/dir1/dir2/dir3` and `/dir4/dir5`?

Comment: Technically, you could turn / into a repo and add most of your file system to the ignore file.

Comment: You may want to ignore a lot of stuff if you want it this way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Still that means create a repository for a single directory `/`.

Comment: No. A git repository is a directory tree, so it can't have multiple "root directories".

Comment: Yes. That's pretty much how git works.

Comment: @iBug. It seems like something that's very obvious but difficult to "prove"

Comment: You can sort of fake it with work trees and sparse checkout. But it is not how git was intended to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A git repository is, or strictly speaking, maintains a directory tree, so it can't have multiple "root directories".

You have many options to work around this, but all of them breaks the idea of having *one* repository. For example,

- You can bind mount (Linux) or hard-link (macOS) different directories into subdirectories of one repository, but they're still inside different folders, despite belonging to the same directory tree
- You can create individual repositories in those folders, and turn them into submodules of the one repository
- You can turn `/` into a repository and ignore as much as you want

But finally, why do you want files into the same repository, while putting them in different places?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have to tell Git what you're doing that's different from the usual setup, you have supply the unusual bits, but it's simple.

Git doesn't require a repository or its worktree to be anyplace in particular. It's got its usual ways of finding them if you don't tell it explicitly, but say you want history for those two subdirs of your home directory. For one-offs it's usually easier to point Git at the parts with command options, when you're doing lots it's easier to feed it overrides from the environment. So:

```
myrepo=~/d123-d45-archive
git init --bare "$myrepo"

GIT_WORK_TREE=~ git -C "$myrepo" add   dir1/dir2/dir3   dir4/dir5

GIT_WORK_TREE=~ git -C "$myrepo" commit -m 'Initial commit of dir1/dir2/dir3 and dir4/dir5'
```

Now: there is no indication outside that bare repository that Git's got tracking data on some of your home directory's contents, so when you want to work with it, you have to tell Git where the pieces are.  The argument equivalent of the `GIT_WORK_TREE` setting above is `--work-tree ~`, the environment equivalent of `-C "$myrepo"` is `GIT_DIR=$myrepo`, if you're batching them up it's easier to do e.g.

```
( export GIT_DIR=$myrepo GIT_WORK_TREE=~
  git add  dir1/dir2/dir3  dir4/dir5
  git commit -m 'new snapshot'
)
```

There's plenty of ways to make this convenient, you can add a git alias to automatically use that pair

```
git config --global alias.homedir \!'git -C ~/d123-d45-archive --work-tree ~'
```

and then you can e.g. `git homedir diff`.  To set the repo up so a reflexive `git add .` doesn't auto-add everything, easiest is

```
mkdir info
printf >info/exclude %s\\n '*' '!*/' '!dir1/dir2/dir3/**' '!dir4/dir5/**'
```

in that repo.  You can have multiple repos tracking different or even overlapping parts of any tree this way—which does mean you get to keep track of all the pieces yourself, be a little careful out there.

Do note that explicitly pointing Git at the context like this bypasses all its reasonable-context checks, Git usually only does *reasonable* things to a filesystem.  You're in "halfway reasonable" territory here, people will do things like this to for instance track the `/etc` directory without needing to ever touch the `/etc` directory itself, that's easy and useful, but a mistaken `clean` can't empty the untracked parts of  `/etc` because you can't, not by mistake. That's not true with your home directory.

At some point you'll want to set up a repo to track your git-specific dotfiles. This is arguably exactly the right way to do it :-)